# Error - (django-taggit) - 'post_list_by_tag' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: python, django, tags

studying django, can't find a solution.  added tags and the site gives an error
studying django, can't find a solution.  added tags and the site gives an error

list.html

````
        <p class="tags">
            Tags:
            {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
                <a href="{% url 'blog:post_list_by_tag' tag.slug %}">
                    {{ tag.name }}
                </a>
                {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        ```


urls.py

    from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    # post views
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),

    # path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/',views.post_detail,name='post_detail'),
    path('<int:post_id>/share/', views.post_share, name='post_share'),
    path('tag/<slug:tag_slug>/', views.post_list, name='post_list_by_tag'),
]
````

Comment: It means that a `tag` has as `slug` an empty string (or there is no `.slug` attribute at all.

Comment: Can you provide the `Tag` model.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  tomorrow I will be at the computer and show everything that is necessary

Comment: tags = TaggableManager()

Comment: everything worked until I did the iterable tag

Comment: {% for post in posts %}
    <h2>
      <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
        {{ post.title }}
      </a>
    </h2>
    <p class="tags">
      Tags:
      {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
        <a href="{% url "blog:post_list_by_tag" tag.slug %}">
          {{ tag.name }}
        </a>
        {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </p>

Comment: def post_list(request, tag_slug=None):
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    tag = None

    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])

    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3) # 3 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
   .........

    return render(request,
                  'blog/post/list.html',
                  {'page': page,
                   'posts': posts,
                   'tag': tag})

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem by deleting all previously created posts without tags